# もらっちゃっていい? what is the meaning of this expression?

Tags: translation

The complete sentence is this

なにあれ私好みなんだけど、もらっちゃっていい？

Is it a way to ask permission?

Thank you.

Comment: A related question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/what-are-these-forms-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%8A-%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%8A Here as well, the ちゃう/じゃう form expresses a kind of carefreeness, asking for permission to do something that maybe you really shouldn't

Comment: Imagine a conversation between two girls. They talk about their boyfriends, and a girl says "The guy over there is my boyfriend", then another girl says jokingly "Wow! He (That) is exactly my ideal type. I almost (and unmaliciously) take him away from you. Is it ok?"

Answer (score 4):

It's a contraction of もらってしまってもいい(ですか). The しまう in there sort of indicates that the speaker is asking for it despite knowing that they might not be the intended recipient (though it doesn't necessarily imply the existence of any specific intended recipient).

Answer (score 3):

Despite the "look" of the phrase, it is generally NOT a way to ask permission if said by a native speaker.  It is a rhetorical question where the speaker is already giving herself (Isn't the speaker a woman?) permission as she utters the line.

"Can I take it (or even "him") home?"

Comment: なぜこの回答にマイナス票が入っているのか全く理解できませんね

Comment: @marasai おひさしぶり～　いあいあ、きっと回答のレベルが高すぎる or 回答は悪くないけど性格（（ry

Answer (score 2):

It means: Can I have it?

Possible nuances:

- Can I have it all?
- Can I have it even though I don't really deserve it in particular?