# What is the meaning of てあげられちゃうんだけど

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances

I have a following line from a manga:

> 持ってきてくれたら「魔法的なこと」見せてあげられちゃうんだけど…
>
> たとえば服を作ったりね♪
>
> If you bring me some, I’ll be able to show you “a magical thing/magical trick/magic”…
>
> Like for example I could make some clothes ♪

Context: Person A that is saying this can do magic and has told Person B what she would need to do magic. So the first bit is her saying that if she is brought this thing she'll be able to show her some more magic and such.

Person A is also currently naked (because of course she is) and wants to get dressed, so second bit is about it also allowing her to make clothes for herself.

Sooo, these two actions, showing more magic AND making clothes using magic (as she does later) don't really seem opposite. So I'm surprised to find they are connected by だけど which I would expect to connect two at least somewhat opposite statements and not main statement and second one making an example. So what's up with that?

Also I have never before seen てあげる be used with ちゃう. Here てあげられる is there to say A will be able to do B a favor of showing her a magic trick. But why append ちゃう? There are only two reasons one might add it to the end of the verb. One is to say that some action was completed completely or/and to indicate the action/event was unfortunate.... I guess it could mean that she would be FULLY able to do something... But yeah I tried searching google and got ONE, ONE hit for てあげられちょう. So yeah, don't know what's the implication/nuance behind that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ちゃう can be used casually in a wide variety of situations. It can describe unexpectedness, [carefreeness](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4781/5010), etc. Saying 見せてあげられちゃう instead of 見せてあげられる in this context implies that showing magical power is not something one can usually expect from Person(?) A.

> - できちゃった!　I did it (although I didn't think I could)!
> - 見ちゃえ!　Just see it (without worrying too much)!

This けど is [for giving background information](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010). Something like 持ってきて欲しいな is left out after this part (hence the ellipsis).

Comment: Isn't it actually ちゃおう in the carefreeness example? Isn't that different.
But leaving that aside, interesting interpretation. If I read you right, A is kinda promoting her magic trick and acting cutesy. "Limited offer of showing one magic trick for materials. So call now and reserve your magic trick." Of course that would not be the literal translation but she hints at it.
As for けど so her being able to do the magic trick if materials are brought would be the setup, background, and the MAIN thing is her making clothes for herself? This does fit.

Comment: @4thdimension Yes, this ちゃう makes her offer sound more or less special.