# Why is ちゃった used here?

Tags: grammar

> いやあ… いつの間にかすごい人になっちゃったんだなあ｡
> 僕の知ってる鴫野は いわゆる オタクっていうか一人で ずっと
> ゲームやってるような奴だったのに｡

Isn't ちゃった used for regrets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ちゃった is a contracted form of -てしまった. This しまう (仕舞う in kanji) originally means "to end (up)". See [this entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%95%E8%88%9E%E3%81%86) on jisho. Just like "to end up" in English does not always imply an undesirable outcome, Japanese ちゃう/てしまう does not always express the sense of regret. Here, すごい人になっちゃった just means "he ended up becoming a great person" or "he turned out to be a great guy".

See also:

- [「しまう」 as an auxiliary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21026/5010)
- [What are these forms: かけちゃお, つないじゃお?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4781/5010)
- [What is the meaning of てあげられちゃうんだけど](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56515/5010)

Comment: Suppose a person was agonizing over the question of which country he should go to and he finally ended up in Mexico. Would this sentence be appropriate: 結局はメキシコに住み着いちゃった。Another question I have is that can I understand  になっちゃった as となった. Because "となる’ also has the nuance of like end up/ wind up, but it is different from the generic になる in that it has the implication that the process of "becoming" was not so straightforward and easy.

Comment: @Stephenshark62 Correct, メキシコに住み着いちゃった does not necessarily carry a regrettable feeling. For となる, can you give an example sentence?