# なんていいから and にしちゃい ？

Tags: grammar, meaning

please help me understand this sentence grammar, especialy なんていいから and にしちゃい parts

- パジャマの話**なんていいから**、早くお昼**にしちゃい**ましょ

I think translation is something like "listen up conversations about pigamas and such, let's do before noon (not so late?)". Context for this sentence was (conversation about pigama is shameful in this situation). But don't sure about this translation.

I translate it this way:

- パジャマの話 - conversations about pigamas
- なんて - such as
- いいから - "listen up" , but maybe it "いい" and "から" - "good" and "since" ?
- 早くお昼に - in time before noon
- しちゃいましょ - let's do

or maybe last two is

- 早くお昼 - before noon
- にしちゃいましょ - let's choose (???)

Thank your for answers!

Comment: For this しちゃいましょ, see this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4781/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いい here means 'it doesn't matter' or 'forget about'. パジャマの話  is 'talking about pyjamas',  and なんて just shows slight disdain for the noun it comes after. お昼 here means 'lunch'.

'Let's stop talking about pyjamas and have lunch already!'