# What is the difference between 死ね and 死んじゃえ?

Tags: word-choice

I was watching an anime (Re:Zero) and I came across a character using "死んじゃえ" instead of the typical "死ね"?
From context "死んじゃえ" seems more forceful but can someone tell me what does it actually mean, how would a Japanese person read "死んじゃえ" in a cultural sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you learned about the subsidiary verb しまう? -じゃえ is the imperative form of -じゃう, which is a contracted form of -てしまう. So 死んじゃえ is the same as 死んでしまえ except that the former is more colloquial.

As a subsidiary verb, (-て)しまう has several functions. For one, it can add a nuance of carefreeness, or the sense of "anyway", "stop worrying", "I don't care", "although it may come with a bad consequence", "I dare say", "no matter what will happen" and so on. See:  [What are these forms: かけちゃお, つないじゃお?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4781/5010)

For example:

- ボタン押しますよ?
  I'll push this button, okay?
- ボタン押しちゃいますよ?
  I'll push this button *(anyway, although it may be dangerous)*, okay?

Likewise, 死んじゃえ sounds like the speaker is aware that it's a bad thing to say and that it may come with a bad consequence. For example, 死んじゃえ is what an angry small girl may say to her mother; she knows that her mom is important, but when she can't help feeling like saying "Die!", she says 死んじゃえ in Japanese. On the other hand, 死ね is a simple and blunt order.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.